# Python: add decision column from string (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I got the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Var1': np.random.rand(10), 'Var2': np.random.rand(10)})
cuts = 'Var1 < 0.8 & Var2 < 0.8'
```

What I want to add is an column, called `'Decision'`, which checks whether the condition in cuts is `True` or `False`. The following code provides exactly what I want:

```
df["Decision"] = np.logical_and(df.Var1 < 0.8, df.Var2 < 0.8)
```

If I do so, I need to convert the string to `df.foo` methods, which seems pretty hard to me due to my negligible regex skills... Is there any possibility to achieve what I want directly from string?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`np.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to generate your column:

```
In [2]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'Var1': np.random.rand(10), 'Var2': np.random.rand(10)})
df

Out[2]:
       Var1      Var2
0  0.982730  0.370334
1  0.269056  0.099330
2  0.697314  0.204711
3  0.272982  0.647933
4  0.096770  0.111819
5  0.278602  0.353552
6  0.959481  0.566532
7  0.552109  0.973224
8  0.563421  0.298835
9  0.395232  0.968710

In [5]:    
df['Decision'] = np.where((df['Var1'] < 0.8) & (df['Var2'] < 0.8), True, False)
df

Out[5]:
       Var1      Var2 Decision
0  0.982730  0.370334    False
1  0.269056  0.099330     True
2  0.697314  0.204711     True
3  0.272982  0.647933     True
4  0.096770  0.111819     True
5  0.278602  0.353552     True
6  0.959481  0.566532    False
7  0.552109  0.973224    False
8  0.563421  0.298835     True
9  0.395232  0.968710    False
```

Here `np.where` will return `True` when the condition is met and `False` otherwise

If you want to use the `cuts` string then you can use [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html#pandas.DataFrame.query) with [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#selection-by-label) you need to use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.isin.html#pandas.Index.isin) with the index and invert the boolean mask using `~` in order to set the `False` rows:

```
In [16]:
cuts = "(Var1 < 0.8) & (Var2 < 0.8)"
df.loc[df.query(cuts).index, 'Decision'] = True
df.loc[~df.index.isin(df.query(cuts).index), 'Decision'] = False
df

Out[16]:
       Var1      Var2 Decision
0  0.982730  0.370334    False
1  0.269056  0.099330     True
2  0.697314  0.204711     True
3  0.272982  0.647933     True
4  0.096770  0.111819     True
5  0.278602  0.353552     True
6  0.959481  0.566532    False
7  0.552109  0.973224    False
8  0.563421  0.298835     True
9  0.395232  0.968710    False
```

Comment: Yeah, this seems like a nice solution. But how to convert `"(Var1 < 0.8) & (Var2 < 0.8)"` into `(df['Var1'] < 0.8) & (df['Var2'] < 0.8)`?

Comment: You could do `df.query(cuts)` but this will return just the positive rows, but you could use this to set the column values, I'll update to show you